# Creating and removing list of radio buttons dynamically with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a standard HTML document with a `div` tag in the body:

`<div id="choicebox"></div>`

I have some JavaScript that aims to populate this `div` tag with a list of radio buttons (there is also some code that inserts a question dynamically but I have omitted it):

```
var questions = [{question:"is the sky blue?",choices:["yes","no","maybe","whatevs"]},{question:"is water wet?",choices:["yes","no","maybe","whatevs"]}];
var questionNumber = 0;
function setChoices(questionNumber){
    var i;
    for(i=0;i<questions[questionNumber].choices.length;i++){
        var choiceBox = document.getElementById("choicebox");
        var choiceElement = document.createElement("input");
        choiceElement.setAttribute("type","radio");
        choiceElement.setAttribute("name","choice");
        choiceElement.setAttribute("id","answ" + (i + 1));
        choiceElement.setAttribute("value",i);
        var labelElement = document.createElement("label");
        labelElement.setAttribute("for","choice");
        labelElement.setAttribute("id","choice_" + (i + 1));
        labelElement.innerHTML = questions[questionNumber].choices[i] + "<br />";
        choiceBox.appendChild(choiceElement);
        choiceBox.appendChild(labelElement);
    }
}
```

What I need is another function that will be associated with the `next` button which will be placed underneath the `choicebox` div. When clicked the question and choices that were displayed will be replaced by the second question and choice set in the `questions` array. Something like:

```
function nextQuestion(){
    var removeQuestion = document.getElementById("question");
    removeQuestion.parentNode.removeChild(removeQuestion);
    var removeChoices = document.getElementById("choicebox");
    choicebox.parentNode.removeChild(choicebox);
    questionNumber++;
    setChoices();
}
```

Any help with this is appreciated. Also let me know if the question is not clear. I have a lot of code omitted from this to make it more concise. I also am trying to code this in vanilla JavaScript but would also be interested in any solutions using jQuery.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

i think this is a scope problem, your function (setChoice) parameter (questionNumber) is the same as the variable defined above the function, so changing the global variable questionNumber won't affect the function, since it will always use the parameter variable (hope this makes sence). Try replacing the setChoice function with this:

```
function setChoices(newQuestionNumber){
if (newQuestionNumber == 'undefined') {
    newQuestionNumber = questionNumber;
}
else {
    //optional, this wil keep the next button working after going to a random question number
    questionNumber = newQuestionNumber;
}
//optional, check if the question exists
if (typeof questions[newQuestionNumber] == 'undefined') {
    throw 'Question '+newQuestionNumber+' does not exist';
}
var i;
for(i=0;i<questions[newQuestionNumber].choices.length;i++){
    var choiceBox = document.getElementById("choicebox");
    var choiceElement = document.createElement("input");
    choiceElement.setAttribute("type","radio");
    choiceElement.setAttribute("name","choice");
    choiceElement.setAttribute("id","answ" + (i + 1));
    choiceElement.setAttribute("value",i);
    var labelElement = document.createElement("label");
    labelElement.setAttribute("for","choice");
    labelElement.setAttribute("id","choice_" + (i + 1));
    labelElement.innerHTML = questions[newQuestionNumber].choices[i] + "<br />";
    choiceBox.appendChild(choiceElement);
    choiceBox.appendChild(labelElement);
}
}`
```

**EDIT**
Are you sure you're using the right variable in the nextQuestion function?

```
var removeChoices = document.getElementById("choicebox");
removeChoices.parentNode.removeChild(removeChoices);
```

instead of

```
var removeChoices = document.getElementById("choicebox");
choicebox.parentNode.removeChild(choicebox);
```

Comment: Thanks for that. But I'm more interested in how I can remove the first set of questions when the `next` button is clicked and have the second question and choices rendered from the `questions` array.

Answer (score 0):

**You said that you would also be interested in any solutions using jQuery, so here you are one:**

```js
function next(){
  $('#choicebox').html(''); //clear choiceElement and labelElement.
  questionNumber++; //increment the question number to make the next question the selected element to work with.
  setChoices(questionNumber); //executes your function to include the question on the html.
}
```